# How to use "If not null Else" to set value?

Tags: f#

In VB.NET you can write this

```
Dim mammal as IAnimal = new Mammal
Dim bird as IAnimal = new Bird
' If mammal is not Nothing, animal is mammal, else it's bird
Dim animal IAnimal = If(mammal, bird) ' animal is mammal

Dim mammal as IAnimal
Dim bird as IAnimal = new Bird
' animal is now Bird
Dim animal IAnimal = If(mammal, bird)
```

And in C#

```
IAnimal mammal = new Mammal()
IAnimal bird = new Bird()
// If mammal is not null, animal is mammal, else it's bird
IAnimal animal = mammal ?? bird; // animal is mammal

IAnimal mammal;
IAnimal bird = new Bird()
// animal is now bird
IAnimal animal = mammal ?? bird;
```

But how to do it in F#? Is there any short syntax like in VB.NET and C#?

I came up with this as a replacement until I find out if/how it's done.

```
let IfNotNullElse (v1, v2) = 
    if v1 <> null then
        v1
    else
        v2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In idiomatic self-contained F# you don't have the idea that anything could be null at any time so it's more common to use the `Option` type and supply default values like this:

```
Some 1 |> Option.defaultValue 2  // 1
None   |> Option.defaultValue 2  // 2
```

However if you are working with .NET nullable references then you could define your own null coalescing operator. Unfortunately `??` is not allowed as an operator name:

```
let (|?) a b = if isNull a then b else a

null |? null |? "a"  // "a"
"a" |? null  // "a"
(null:string) |? null  // null
```

But beware that there is no lazy evaluation here. The expressions to the right of `|?` are always evaluated in full.